# CPU render result differs from CUDA's one on smoke

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, smoke-simulation, volumetrics

The final result of a smoke render differs if using GPU (NVIDIA 1050 Ti) or using CPU (AMD 1300X). Any idea why?

**CPU render - Volume sampling 0.1 - Volume bounces: 0**
[image: CPU render - Volume sampling 0.1]

**CUDA render - Volume sampling 0.1 - Volume bounces: 0**
[image: GPU render - Volume sampling 0.1]

Having tests I found it out that it is something related to the volume sampling. Decreasing the value solves partially the problem for the CPU so it becomes nearly the one obtained with the GPU but... there still are enormous differences.

No settings have been touched from render to render.

**CPU render - Volume sampling 0.01 - Volume bounces: 15**
[image: CPU render - Volume sampling 0.01]

**CUDA render - Volume sampling 0.01 - Volume bounces: 15**
[image: GPU render - Volume sampling 0.1]

**BLENDER VERSIONS TESTED:**

**LINUX:**

- 17:2.79.b.git3.32432d91-1 from the arch's repository.
- 2.79b official
- 2.79-c9608047472 experimental official
- 2.80-405c6c077f6 experimental official

*in the 2.8 I can't bake so can't actually test... Is maybe the smoke simulation still under development?*

**BLEND FILE:**

[image]

*Opened bug report here: https://developer.blender.org/T55765*

Comment: Looks like a bug.

Comment: going to add to the question the blender version. in the meantime is this: 17:2.79.b.git3.32432d91-1 from the arch's repository.

Comment: does the same happen with the official release?

Comment: have not tested, going to take a test with the official.

Comment: it happens also with the official one.

Comment: Yeah, this looks like a bug. CPU has a more optimized volume sampling method than GPU, but you shouldn't get differences like this. I'd recommend reporting this one to Blender devs

Comment: going to take also a test with latest experimental builds, if the thing persist i will open a bug report ^^

Comment: opened bug at: https://developer.blender.org/T55765